# how to play mp3 file from a URL

Tags: javascript

this is a player from codepen. https://codepen.io/markhillard/pen/Hjcwu

how to change it to play my own .mp3 file from a URL

for example if my mp3 file URL is [www.website.com/audiofile.mp3](http://www.website.com/audiofile.mp3)

i tried changing mediaPath to 'https://www.website.com' and "file": "JLS_ATI" to "file": "audiofile.mp"

but it didnt work

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        'use strict'
        var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
        if (supportsAudio) {
            // initialize plyr
            var player = new Plyr('#audio1', {
                controls: [
                    'restart',
                    'play',
                    'progress',
                    'current-time',
                    'duration',
                    'mute',
                    'volume',
                    'download'
                ]
            });
            // initialize playlist and controls
            var index = 0,
                playing = false,
                mediaPath = 'https://archive.org/download/mythium/',
                extension = '',
                tracks = [{
                    "track": 1,
                    "name": "All This Is - Joe L.'s Studio",
                    "duration": "2:46",
                    "file": "JLS_ATI"
                }, {
                    "track": 2,
                    "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                    "duration": "8:30",
                    "file": "BS_TF"
         
                }],
                buildPlaylist = $.each(tracks, function(key, value) {
                    var trackNumber = value.track,
                        trackName = value.name,
                        trackDuration = value.duration;
                    if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
                        trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
                    }
                    $('#plList').append('<li> \
                        <div class="plItem"> \
                            <span class="plNum">' + trackNumber + '.</span> \
                            <span class="plTitle">' + trackName + '</span> \
                            <span class="plLength">' + trackDuration + '</span> \
                        </div> \
                    </li>');
                }),
                trackCount = tracks.length,
                npAction = $('#npAction'),
                npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
                audio = $('#audio1').on('play', function () {
                    playing = true;
                    npAction.text('Now Playing...');
                }).on('pause', function () {
                    playing = false;
                    npAction.text('Paused...');
                }).on('ended', function () {
                    npAction.text('Paused...');
                    if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                        index++;
                        loadTrack(index);
                        audio.play();
                    } else {
                        audio.pause();
                        index = 0;
                        loadTrack(index);
                    }
                }).get(0),
                btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').on('click', function () {
                    if ((index - 1) > -1) {
                        index--;
                        loadTrack(index);
                        if (playing) {
                            audio.play();
                        }
                    } else {
                        audio.pause();
                        index = 0;
                        loadTrack(index);
                    }
                }),
                btnNext = $('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
                    if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                        index++;
                        loadTrack(index);
                        if (playing) {
                            audio.play();
                        }
                    } else {
                        audio.pause();
                        index = 0;
                        loadTrack(index);
                    }
                }),
                li = $('#plList li').on('click', function () {
                    var id = parseInt($(this).index());
                    if (id !== index) {
                        playTrack(id);
                    }
                }),
                loadTrack = function (id) {
                    $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
                    $('#plList li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');
                    npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
                    index = id;
                    audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file + extension;
                    updateDownload(id, audio.src);
                },
                updateDownload = function (id, source) {
                    player.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
                        $('a[data-plyr="download"]').attr('href', source);
                    });
                },
                playTrack = function (id) {
                    loadTrack(id);
                    audio.play();
                };
            extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
            loadTrack(index);
        } else {
            // no audio support
            $('.column').addClass('hidden');
            var noSupport = $('#audio1').text();
            $('.container').append('<p class="no-support">' + noSupport + '</p>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: "It didn't work." What happened, what didn't happen? Do you see any 404-ing requests in your browser's network inspector?

Comment: Are they any errors on the console that may point to the problem? Do you see a network request to the mp3 when looking at the network tab of your browser's debug tools, and if so, what is its status?